# truncate all rows from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to test that some code works if a dataframe has no rows in it. In SQL you can clean all the rows out of a table with the truncate command. I found the Pandas [truncate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.truncate.html) command, but can't get rid of the very last row. I did this:

```
df.truncate(after=0, before=0)
```

..but it left the 0th row. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `before=1`?

Comment: I just did then - if you have no 'after', it just removes the 0th row and leaves everything else, if I leave the 'after' in there, I get `ValueError: Truncate: 0 must be after 1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `truncate` working on my side

```
df.truncate(before=-1, after=-1)
Out[835]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B, C]
Index: []
```

Comment: Am using `pd.__version__` of `'0.19.2'`

Comment: @cardamom   pd.__version__: '0.22.0'

Comment: @cardamom just make sure you do not have negative index dude : -)

Answer (score 13):

You can use `df.head(0)`

```
In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame([{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}, {'foo': 3, 'bar': 4}])

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
   bar  foo
0    2    1
1    4    3

In [5]: df.head(0)
Out[5]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [bar, foo]
Index: []
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `drop` by all index values:

```
df1 = df.drop(df.index)
```

Or `DataFrame` constructor with `columns` parameter only:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':list('ab'), 'b':range(2)})
```

---

```
df1 = df.drop(df.index)
print (df1)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b]
Index: []
```